# How to label in pandas based on values in other columns? Without duplicating and without rewriting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, label

Good morning!

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'Participant': ['Mike', 'John', 'Miranda', 'Sam', 'Jake', 'Sally'],
    'Job': ['worker', 'CEO', 'worker', 'MBA', 'worker', 'MBA'],
    'Business': ['oil', 'ecommerce', 'fmcg', 'restaurant', 'hotel', 'ecommerce'],
    'Label1': [np.nan, 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Europe', 
                         'Asia', np.nan],
}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[["Label2", "Label3"]] = np.nan
```

The task is to fill in columns Label1, Label2, Label3 so that the previous entries in these columns are **not** erased and the same values are **not** duplicated.

The conditions are following:

1. If Job = "worker" AND Business = "oil", so write "USA" in corresponding row in one of the "Label" columns (Label1, Label2 or Label3 - the one that is empty).
2. If Job = "worker" OR Job = "CEO" OR Business = "FMCG", so write "SouthAmerica" in corresponding row.
3. If Job = "MBA" OR Business = "hotel", so write "Europe" in corresponding row.

The result has to be following:
[result_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpAwx.jpg)

P.S. My approach is this:[my approach snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quGiI.png) . Unfortunately, it doesn't avoid duplicating + it won't allow to place multiple labels (for example: Label1 = "USA", Label2 = "SouthAmerica", Label3 = "Europe").

Thank you in advance. Even if you direct me into right area where to find an answer, it would be great.

Comment: what means `doesn't avoid duplicating` ? Why expected ouput for `Label2 , Label3` not match conditions?

Comment: @jezrael, thank you for reaching me here. Regarding `doesn't avoid duplicating` I mean that if I use my approach I will get "USA" in all three columns (Label1, Label2, Label3). What I want is to get "USA" in only one column. Regarding the `no-matching` of the expected output and the conditions, it could be a typo from my side. This data sample and conditions are dummy. I hope my question overall is clear.

Answer (score 0):

This code yielded me the result you are showing in the snapshot.
Try to proceed as follows:

- first, define all the conditions (without specifying anything about the labels)
- then, make a function that takes the condition you want to evaluate along with the value corresponding to it,
- the function fills the labels in the order you mentioned (details are in the comments)

```py
def fill_label(df, cond, val):
    # loop over the rows that satisfy the condition
    for idx in df[cond].index:
        v1 = df.loc[idx, "Label1"]

        # check if the value is already there (to avoid duplicates)
        if (v1 == val):
            continue
        
        # check if the value is a float (to avoid errors with np.isnan)
        # then check if it is NaN
        if isinstance(v1, float) and np.isnan(v1):
            # use `df.loc[idx, label]` to alter the dataframe in-place
            df.loc[idx, "Label1"] = val
            continue
        
        # Only move to this part when the value you are trying to add
        # is not in Label1 and Label1 is already filled

        # Proceed similarly with Label2
        v2 = df.loc[idx, "Label2"]
        if (v2 == val):
            continue

        if isinstance(v2, float) and np.isnan(v2):
            df.loc[idx, "Label2"] = val
            continue
        
        # Set the value in the last available Label column
        df.loc[idx, "Label3"] = val

data = {
    'Participant': ['Mike', 'John', 'Miranda', 'Sam', 'Jake', 'Sally'],
    'Job': ['worker', 'CEO', 'worker', 'MBA', 'worker', 'MBA'],
    'Business': ['oil', 'ecommerce', 'fmcg', 'restaurant', 'hotel', 'ecommerce'],
    'Label1': [np.nan, 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Europe', 
                     'Asia', np.nan],
}
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[["Label2", "Label3"]] = np.nan

# define the three conditions first
cond1 = (df.Job == "worker") & (df.Business == "oil")
cond2 = (df.Job == "worker") | (df.Job == "CEO") | (df.Business  == "FMCG")
cond3 = (df.Job== "MBA") | (df.Business == "hotel")

# fill labels in order
fill_label(df, cond1, "USA")
fill_label(df, cond2, "SouthAmerica")
fill_label(df, cond3, "Europe")
```

Comment: it works perfectly.  It is my hope that one day I can "cast" these things myself. Thank you for your help!